# Invalid YGDirection 'row' should be one of: (inherit, ltr, rtl) - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I get the below error on iOS as a dismissable error. (pressing esc button hides the error and shows my app.)

> Invalid YGDirection 'row' should be one of: (inherit, ltr, rtl) -
>   React Native

I am using [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) on my project but I don't think this error caused by the component.

Since react-native uses flex layout, we should be able to use the `flex-direction` attribute.

My wrapper component is below:

```
const Wrapper = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  align-items: ${props => props.align};
  justify-content: ${props => props.justify};
  flex-direction: ${props => props.direction};
  flex-grow: ${props => props.grow};
  flex-shrink: ${props => props.shrink};
`;

Wrapper.defaultProps = {
  direction: 'column',
  align: 'flex-start',
  justify: 'flex-start',
  grow: 1,
  shrink: 0,
};
```

Am I missing something?
The full error is something like below:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem and solved it after few hours.

Search for any Text component with direction prop in it.
`<Text direction={value} />`
change it to
`<Text dir={value} />`
or any prop name you like

Base on your code, it would be in your Wrapper with the prop name direction.

Comment: Renaming direction prop to dir (or something else) worked. Thanks.

Comment: there should really be better error messages from the react native team...

Answer (score 1):

if you using nativebase and get the same error,
find the `<Flex></Flex>` tag that have `direction="row"` options, comment that options will solve the error,

you can also replace `<Flex></Flex>` with `<HStack></HStack>` if you want to achieve a similar result

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in my RN project. For me, the issue occurred because of flex-direction.

If you are using flex, instead of `direction`, it should be `flexDirection`.

So instead of:

```
<Flex direction="row"></Flex>
```

Do this:

```
<Flex flexDirection={"row"}></Flex>
```

This solved my issue.